# combine different row's values in table in r

Tags: r, format, reformat, reformatting

I need to re-format a table in R.

I have a table like this.

```
ID  category   
1   a   
1   b   
2   c   
3   d   
4   a   
4   c  
5   a
```

**And I want to reform it as**

```
ID  category1   category2  
1           a           b  
2           c        null  
3           d        null  
4           a           c  
5           a        null
```

Is this doable in R?

Comment: Some explanation of how you are going from X to Y would be good

Comment: Will do so next time : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very straightforward "long to wide" type of reshaping problem, but you need a secondary "id" (or "time") variable.

You can try using `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package and use `dcast` to reshape from long to wide. `getanID` will create a new column called ".id" that would be used as your "time" variable:

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast.data.table(getanID(mydf, "ID"), ID ~ .id, value.var = "category")
#    ID 1  2
# 1:  1 a  b
# 2:  2 c NA
# 3:  3 d NA
# 4:  4 a  c
# 5:  5 a NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!

Comment: And ye olde base R equivalent - `reshape(cbind(dat,time=ave(dat$ID,dat$ID,FUN=seq_along)), idvar="ID", direction="wide", times="time")`

Comment: If there is a new col 3 I can just use                          dcast.data.table(getanID(mydf, "ID"), ID **+col 3** ~ .id, value.var = "category") right? thanks

Comment: @KarlTian, not sure I fully follow your question. If it's just one column, then yes. If you're trying to spread out multiple columns, the syntax would be a little different and would require the development version of "data.table" (or base R's `reshape`).

Answer (score 1):

Same as Ananda's, but using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(cat_row = paste0("category", 1:n())) %>%
    spread(key = cat_row, value = category)

# Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
# 
#   ID category1  category2
# 1  1         a          b
# 2  2         c         NA
# 3  3         d         NA
# 4  4         a          c
# 5  5         a         NA
```

Comment: Thank you : )                                                                                             I was trying to download the package "tidyr" from CRAN, but it keep failing and give me error like this                                                   {Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/tidyr_0.2.0.zip'
Warning in install.packages :}

Comment: @KarlTian that's strange, it is on CRAN. You could try a different CRAN mirror (though RStudio's tends to be reliable), or install straight from github.